# Nhibernate mapping by code, Could not determine type for property

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

I have entity object `User` and value object `Profile`.

```
public class User : Entity<Guid>
{
    ...
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    ...
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using nhibernate mapping by code and I'm mapping Profile value object in `UserMap.cs` as component like  `Component(c => c.Profile, ProfileMap.Mapping());`

ProfileMap.cs

```
public class ProfileMap
{
    public static Action<IComponentMapper<Profile>> Mapping()
    {
        return c =>
        {
           ...
           c.Property(p => p.User);               
        }
    }
}
```

On unit mapping tests I'm getting error with inner exception message

> "Could not determine type for: MyApp.Domain.Model.User,
>   MyApp.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>   for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(User)"}

p.s. when I comment out mapping `User` property from `ProfileMap` and leaving `Profile` property in `UserMap` mapping works.

Comment: Why don't you create an extension method to be used in the mapping class like this: `this.ProfileComponent(x => x.Profile)`. Or at least `ProfileComponent(x => x.Profile, x => x.ProfileMapping())`.

Comment: thanks, but do I solve my issue with extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is most probably not a Property, but a relation type (many-to-many, or many-to-one or something). Most probably it is the components parent.

```
public static Action<IComponentMapper<Profile>> Mapping()
{
    return c =>
    {
       ...
       c.Parent(p => p.User);               
    }
}
```

Comment: ... but its type is a reference to an entity. You cannot map it as "Property".